Simplest position where promotion to rook is unique drawing move
How many pieces and pawns are needed for a position where:

White has only one move to draw
That move is a rook promotion
All other moves by white lose

I know this position with 9 pieces and pawns:
[Title "F. Lazard, 1935"]
[FEN "8/3P4/3b4/8/8/1p2k2p/1Pp4P/2K5 w - - 0 1"]

1. d8=R! Bf4 2. Rd2!


https://lichess.org/forum/general-chess-discussion/drawing-by-underpromotion?page=2, last posting, play to R promotion at the end, have 8. (Jan Rusinek, 64, 1978)

Six units (verified by both the Nalimov and Syzygy tablebases):
[Title "NDE(?) after Lazard: White to move and draw"]
[FEN "8/1P7/r4k1b/8/8/8/p7/K7 w - - 0 1"]

1. b8=R! Bg7 2. Rb2!

It's easier to modify the Lazard position to a 7-unit setting:
[Title "Lazard 1935, v. NDE: WTM and draw"]
[FEN "8/4bP2/8/8/8/3p2k1/3Pp/4K3 w - - 0 1"]

1. f8=R! Bh4! 2. Rf2!

As in Lazard's study, the final position is mutual Zugzwang:
if it were White to move, Black would win (e.g. 3 Rxe2 Kf3+).
This also works with the Black Bishop on g5, f6, or d8 instead of e7.

Congratulations - wonderful stuff

I think I found a position with 7 units
[Title "White to play and draw"]
[FEN "6Kn/6PP/6kb/7r/8/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. gxh8=R! Rf5

1.gh8Q? (or 1.gh8B?) loses to 1...Rf5!
1.Kh8? (or 1.Kf8?) loses to 1...Bxg7
1.gh8N!? Kf6 2.Ng6/Nf7 Bg7 3.h8Q Bxh8 4.Nxh8 Ra5 is a theoretical win : 5.Kh7 Ra3 6.Kg8 Ra4 7.Kh7 Rg4Z -+
But the rook promotion 1.gh8R!= saves the day with the stalemate trick. Black can call it a day with 1...Rf5= or let White escape with 1...Kf5 or 1...Be3 to a drawn R+B vs R endgame, but they cannot win.

Previous answer :
A bid with 8 men. I am sure that 7 is possible, I don't know about 6.
[Title "White to play and draw"]
[FEN "K7/PP6/P7/8/7k/6b1/1p6/1b6 w - - 0 1"]

1. b8=R! Be4 2. Rb7 b1=Q

1.b8Q? Be4+ 2.Qb7 b1Q (or 2...b1B) mates on the next move.
1.b8R! Be4+ (1...Be5 2.Rb4+=) 2.Rb7 Bxb7 (most other moves are stalemate) 3.ab b1Q 4.b8Q=

This 7-unit draw-study is in PDB with id P1394451.
[Title "Marek Kacewicz; Szachy, Jun 1980, 36v"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[fen "8/p2b4/PP5b/K7/5k2/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]

1.b7! Ke4 2. b8=R! Bd2+ 3. Rb4+ Bxb4+ 4. Kxb4 Kd3 5. Kb3 Be6+ 6. Kb2=

(If 2 b8=Q? then 2 ... Bd2+ 3. Qb4+ Kd3! 4. Qxd2+ Kxd2 and Black wins.)

Very nice study ! I was not too far from this matrix with my 8-men position...
